# Scheduled Timer won't fire

Tags: swift, timer, command-line-interface, nstimer

I am trying out Swift as a language for CLI tool, which is supposed to serve as a simple web crawler.

In my [`main`](https://github.com/pajapro/BoligScrapper/blob/master/Sources/BoligScrapper/main.swift#L28-L29) file I create an instance of `APIFetcher` class. In the initialiser of `APIFetcher` I [instantiate an instance of `Timer` with the given time interval](https://github.com/pajapro/BoligScrapper/blob/master/Sources/BoligScrapperCore/APIFetcher.swift#L16-L38). Once I call `startQuerying` method, it adds `Timer` to the main run loop - at this point I would expect `performTask` method would be invoked, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
    @available(OSX 10.12, *)
    public init(with interval: TimeInterval) {
        self.timer = Timer(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.performTask()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

    public func startQuerying(_ url: URL) {
        guard let unwrappedTimer = self.timer else { return }

        RunLoop.main.add(unwrappedTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    }

    func performTask() {
        print("Performed scheduled task")
    }
```

Comment: A CLI doesn't have a runloop. You have to start the run loop explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) you are right, I added the timer to run loop, but never actually started it. This fixes the whole issue:

```
RunLoop.main.add(unwrappedTimer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
RunLoop.main.run()
```

Also, see [When Would You Use a Run Loop?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW24) documentation